# Providing the model for a component as a slot

Tags: aurelia

Consider the following two custom elements in Aurelia (list & row):

**row.html**

```
<template>
  <span>${name}</span>
</template>
```

**row.js**

```
export class Row
{
  name = "Marry";
}
```

**list.html**

```
<template>
  The List
  <ol>
    <li repeat.for="r of rows">
      <slot name="rowItem" model.bind="r"></slot>
    </li>
  </ol>
</template>
```

**list.js**

```
import { bindable } from 'aurelia-framework';

export class List
{
    @bindable
    rows = [{name: "John"}];
}
```

The `app` will tie them together:

**app.html**

```
<template>
  <require from="./list"></require>
  <require from="./row"></require>

  <list rows.bind="users">
    <row slot="rowItem"></row>
  </list>
</template>
```

**app.js**

```
export class App
{
  users = [{name: "Joe"}, {name: "Jack"}, {name: "Jill"}];
}
```

The problem is that the model for the `row` is not set correctly. All I get as the output is the following:

```
The List
  1.
  2.
  3.
```

So the question is; how can I provide the model for a slot in Aurelia?

Here's [a Gist](https://gist.run/?id=4fe71229cf7bff6b990d0578be91ff37) to demonstrate the problem in action.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Slots aren't going to work for what you want to do. It's a known limitation of slots in Aurelia. Slots can't be dynamically generated (such as inside a repeater).

Luckily, there's another option to accomplish what you want: template parts.

Template parts aren't well documented (my fault, I should have written the docs for them). But we have some docs in our [cheat sheet](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/cheat-sheet/9). I've modified your gist to show how to use them: https://gist.run/?id=1c4c93f0d472729490e2934b06e14b50

Basically, you'll have a template element in your custom element's HTML that has the `replaceable` attribute on it along with a `part="something"` attribute (where `something` is replaced with the template part's name. Then, when you use the custom element, you'll have another template element that has the `replace-part="something"` attribute (again, where `something` is replaced with the template part's name). It looks like this:

*list.html*

```
<template>
  The List
  <ol>
    <li repeat.for="row of rows">
      <template replaceable part="row-template">
        ${row}
      </template>
    </li>
  </ol>
</template>
```

*app.html*

```
<template>
  <require from="./list"></require>
  <require from="./row"></require>

  <list rows.bind="users">
    <template replace-part="row-template">
      <row name.bind="row.name"></row>
    </template>
  </list>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great. I've spent some time on your Gist and it seems that  **(1)** `${row}` in *list.html* has got no purpose and can be omitted. **(2)** The `row` (as in `row.name`) in *app.html* refers to `row of rows`.  This is not a good idea since it means `app` should know the inner workings of the `list`. Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: `${row}` in `list.html` actually does have a purpose (sort of). If you use the custom element without replacing the replaceable part, then the template in `list.html` will be used. It won't be pretty, in this case, but it will be used.

Comment: I agree that having the View that is using the custom element have detailed knowledge of the inner workings of the custom element is less than ideal, but for what you're specifically trying to do, I'm not sure there's a better way to do it. Hopefully, someone will come by and show us a better way.

Comment: Actually, as a further comment regarding "inner workings." The named slot model that the shadow dom uses will cause this same type of "tightly coupled" code, so it's a bit of a "damned if you do, damned if you don't" deal.