# How to set the model of a child slot by the parent component

Tags: aurelia

I've already asked [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40028909/providing-the-model-for-a-component-as-a-slot/40029426?noredirect=1#comment67344235_40029426) rather close to this one (just so they are not confused). Here I'm not trying to generate slots dynamically.

So consider a parent component and a child component which is handed over to the parent by its own parent. I want to know how can I set a model for the child component (a slot) by its parent. Here's the code (also [in Gist](https://gist.run/?id=c1bba4e5442bd63b6183fc002783dd53)) to explain the question is detail:

*child.js*

```
import { bindable } from 'aurelia-framework';

export class Child
{
  @bindable
  name = "** child's model is not set **";
}
```

*child.html*

```
<template>
  <span>${name}</span>
</template>
```

*parent.js*

```
export class App
{
  users = [{name: "Joe"}, {name: "Jack"}, {name: "Jill"}];
}
```

*parent.html*

```
<template>
  The Parent
  <ul>
    <slot name="childComponent" model.bind="rows[0]"></slot>
  </ul>
</template>
```

And of course, `app` root component which glues everything together:

*app.js*

```
export class App
{
  users = [{name: "Joe"}, {name: "Jack"}, {name: "Jill"}];
}
```

*app.html*

```
<template>
  <require from="./parent"></require>
  <require from="./child"></require>

  <parent rows.bind="users">
    <child slot="childComponent"></child>
  </parent>

  <input value.bind="users[0].name">
</template>
```

My problem here is that there's no `model` set for the child component.

Answer (score 2):

`model` is a bindable property on the `compose` element, not on `slot` elements. The polyfill is mostly implemented in this file: https://github.com/aurelia/templating/blob/master/src/shadow-dom.js#L122 If you Ctrl-F for "model" you won't even find the word in the file.

Comment: I have managed to solve my problem using replaceable template which makes me wonder, what's the use for slots if replaceable templates can do the same and more!?

Comment: `slot` is a part of ShadowDOM v1. `replaceable` is a part of Aurelia.